# Java parsing json fields into Period

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, period

If I have a json response that looks like this:

```
{
    year: 40,
    month: 2,
    day: 21
}
```

That represents someone's age. And I have a class to store that:

```
public class User {
    private Period age;
}
```

How do I parse the individual numbers and create a `Period` object?

Comment: Nobody know what's inside your `Period` class, but I think what you are looking for is to parse and extract the values from that JSON representation. Am I correct?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ sorry I shouldve mentioned that, it's the standard Period class from Java 8's time library. And yeah basically, i need to take each number and do something like `Period.of(year, month, day)`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jackson you can write a simple `JsonDeserializer` like this:

```
class UserJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User>
{
  public User deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                                        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
    int year = node.get("year").asInt();
    int month = node.get("month").asInt();
    int day = node.get("day").asInt();
    Period period = Period.of(year, month, day);
    return new User(period); // User needs corresponding constructor of course
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a customer deserializer. See [the Awita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35636476/3537858).

However, just for the record,  there is [an official datatype Jackson module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) which recognizes Java 8 Date & Time API data types. It represents `Period` as a string in the ISO-8601 format, not as object your stated. But if you are willing to change the format, you can consider using that module.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonPeriod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        final Period period = Period.of(1, 2, 3);
        final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(period);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"P1Y2M3D"
```